# Scikit-Learn: set_param() for custom estimator sets nested parameter before component

Tags: scikit-learn

I implemented several custom estimators, following the [developer guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator), so that all of them are inheriting from [BaseEstimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html#sklearn.base.BaseEstimator). Some of these use other scikit-learn estimators or transformers as attributes (say for example, to build an ensemble). Inheriting from BaseEstimator should give me the convenience of accessing the parameters through get_params() and setting them through set_params() as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html#sklearn.base.BaseEstimator), in the form component__parameter, for example for use in grid search. Find below a minimal example.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

class MyForecaster(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, base_estimator=LinearRegression()):
        self.base_estimator = base_estimator

    def fit(self, X, y):
        pass

    def predict(self, X, y):
        pass

# instantiate forecaster and set parameters
mf = MyForecaster()
mf.set_params(**{"base_estimator" : "ElasticNet", "base_estimator__alpha": 0.05})
```

This fails with:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter alpha for estimator LinearRegression. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

This indicates it tries to set the params with first for the nested attribute, instead of checking first if I want to overwrite the "higher level" attribute (ElasticNet has the attribute alpha, LinearRegression not).

One way to handle this would be to overwrite set_params() for each estimator, to make sure that it is handled correctly.

Is there any "built in" way to achieve this, which I simply overlooked another solution? Is this really intended behavior by scikit-learn?

## Edit:

So indeed due to some very big coincidence a very similar issue seems to have been fixed with version 0.19.1. However, my particular case still fails, only the case with Pipelines is fixed!

To make it reproduciable I copied the current code of set_params() into my minimal example (only added comment in line 20)

```
1   def set_params(self, **params):
2       if not params:
3           # Simple optimization to gain speed (inspect is slow)
4           return self
5       valid_params = self.get_params(deep=True)
6
7       nested_params = defaultdict(dict)  # grouped by prefix
8       for key, value in params.items():
9           key, delim, sub_key = key.partition('__')
10          if key not in valid_params:
11              raise ValueError('Invalid parameter %s for estimator %s. '
12                               'Check the list of available parameters '
13                               'with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.' %
14                               (key, self))
15
16          if delim:
17              nested_params[key][sub_key] = value
18          else:
19              setattr(self, key, value)
20              #valid_params[key] = value
21
22      for key, sub_params in nested_params.items():
23          valid_params[key].set_params(**sub_params)
24
25      return self
```

It fails, because it will set the attribute in line 19, but as it not updates valid_params, it will still fail in the next iteration, when the attribute is tried to be set. So I added line 20 which would fix this.
It does work as tested in the current fix of 0.19.1, as it was only tested for Pipelines. [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f/sklearn/pipeline.py#L29), set_param() is overwritten to first call _set_param() of [_BaseComposition](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f1ab2d060fd49c94a6e3386291a684ec7/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py), where appereantly this is handled.

Should I raise this in the scikit-learn github or reopen the other issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the [fix](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9945) mentioned in @TomDLT's answer fixed a very similar issue and led to the fix above making it most likely into a future version of sklearn ([9999](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9999)).

So for here: if you come across the problem in the meantime, either use the code above to overwrite set_params() or wait for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. It has been reported [a week ago](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9944), and has already [been fixed](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9945) and backported in `v0.19.1`, which has been released [yesterday](https://twitter.com/amuellerml/status/922498866376773632).

The easiest fix is to update scikit-learn to `v0.19.1` (or to master dev branch).

Comment: Thanks Tom, indeed due to a big coincidence a very similar issue was fixed in 0.19.1. I checked SO for similar issues, but not the git, as I wasn't sure if this is an issue on their side or mine. My example still fails though, see edit above. Are you involved with sklearn? If you think this is an scikit issue, should I approach them in the git?

Comment: Indeed, your example still fails. Thanks a lot for both reporting it and providing a clean fix! ([#9999](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9999))